# Runtime checks of dynamic cast

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

```
dynamic_cast <new type> (exp)
```

I read in the documentation that,
If the new type is a pointer/ref to derived and expression is a pointer/ref to base ,then only a runtime check is done by dynamic cast.
What actually are those checks all about??

Edit :  what are the runtime checks involved in doin a sidecast.

Comment: "What actually are those checks all about?" - checking that whatever you cast to/from are actually part of the same inheritance hierarchy. You can't just cast between unrelated types.

Comment: [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is actually pretty good at explaining this.

Comment: @Mgetz i didnt get those next few lines which follow

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) point 5. Part 5c is usually the most useful for me (return null if cannot cast pointer). You can think of it like Java `if (ptr instanceof Class)` in C++ is `if (dynamic_cast<Class*>(ptr))`

Comment: @Hitobat Unlike Java, C++ has access control on inheritance and repeated inheritance, so it's more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A side cast (5b) is when `exp` is not of a base type of `new_type`. Example: if `exp` is a pointer to a `B` which points to an object of class `T`, where `T` derives from both `B` and `D`, then

```
dynamic_cast<D*> (exp)
```

is a side cast which yields a pointer to the `D` base of `T`.

Comment: "D base  of T",what is meant by this

Comment: When you initialize an object whose class has multiple parent classes, an object of each parent type is constructed under the hood. In this example, `T` derives from `B` and `D`. This cast gives you a pointer to the `D` parent object, or base.